# openshift wordpress serving old pages, ignoring header.php changes

Tags: php, wordpress, openshift

I have openshift with wordpress cartridge.
I need to edit/write php files, and have done so via Wordpress theme editor page.
( i have confirmed by sftp that it did edit the files)
Also I have also edited php files localy, then uploaded them by sftp.

( I do not use git, because by default it does not include all the relevant directories,  and is useless to me)

All the php files are in directory:
/var/lib/openshift/53....555/app-root/data/themes/purple-pro

What is supposed to happen, is html output is meant to change, after php file changes.

It does not.

Answer (score 2):

Try restarting your app with `rhc app restart -a <yourappname>`

Answer (score 1):

For other people having problems with openshift and editing php files.

It seems all PHP Files are cached/compiled, and even deleting a info.php file, still serves a old output webpage.

recomended solution is: use git so it can restart your webserver ( while also it deletes your wp-content directory ffs)

Actually works solution is:
use a linux terminal:

rhc app restart -a myapp

Viola, all the php files now run.